# Searching, sorting, paginating and filtering DIVs using Jquery/AJAX/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm working on the front-end of my project and doing the back-end later. I've ran into a snag though.  I have a list of DIVs (want them to be collapsible as well) that are suppose to show various apartments around a given zip code. Problem is, I don't know where to go to look for these things:

- Firstly, I wish to sort these divs by name or ranking.
- Secondly, I
  want to be able to search these results and toss out the ones that
  they do not want, i.e. I type in A, all apartments that begin with
  letters B-Z disappear in the list. I think in p after A, all Aa-Az
  letters disappear from the list, etc.
- Thirdly, should I use jQuery to paginate my results or should I use PHP instead?
- Lastly, I have a filter box.  I want to do the same as above except with different selectable options (on the fly using AJAX).  User selects, 1 to 3 bedroom apartments, no pets,
  and hits filter... boom, list of apartments with values.

Is there anything that I can use using jQuery/Javascript to speed up this process that also degrades when Javascript's disabled?  I know this sounds like a lot, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well for this to work without javascript, and still behave like you want, i guess you have to build this in pure old html (with form post's / links) and then add jquery ajax functionality to make it prettier and faster when javascript is enabled.

If i were doing this, i would build it with form post's that return the whole page (when javascript is disabled) and add jquery events on page load to prevent default form post and instead use ajax post to only partial load your pages and aply transition effects.

One last thing, if you have a lot of data to show on page use pagination and sorting at database level, return only the visible content of your page. This will work with and without javascript, and is scalable (with lots of results it becomes unmanageable to it in javascript)